# Issue with namespace scoping

Tags: c++, scope, namespaces

Why does the following code work (`Utilities` is a namespace):

```
template<>
std::map<uint8_t, std::string> A::Utilities::EnumDescription<A::B::Tabs, uint8_t>::descMap =
{...};
```

while this one does not?

```
namespace A
{
namespace B
{

    template<>
    std::map<uint8_t, std::string> A::Utilities::EnumDescription<Tabs, uint8_t>::descMap =  // Error --> descMap
    {...};

}
}
```

> Error C2888: symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'B'
>   Member "A::Utilities::EnumDescription::descMap [with E=A::B::Tabs, T=uint8_t]" cannot be specialized in the current scope

Comment: Neither posted piece of prose compiles as C++ (nothing to talk of "does work").

Comment: `{...}` is pseudo-code.

Comment: @Pietro -- it's pseudo-code that doesn't compile. Don't post code that people who want to try it out have to edit.

Answer (score 4):

Full and partial specialisations of a template `X` can be defined in the same namespace where `X` is defined, or in a namespace enclosing (directly or indirectly) that namespace, but cannot be defined in other namespaces (such as child or "cousin" namespaces of `X`'s namespace). That's just the rules of the language.

In your case, the template involved is `A::Utilities::EnumDescription`, so the specialisation must happen within `A::Utilities`, `A`, or the global namespace.

Comment: Shouldn't `namespace A { namespace B { Tabs } }` and `A::B::Tabs` be equivalent in this context?

Comment: Does the compiler look for `Tabs` in `A::Utilities`?

Comment: @Pietro The problem is not with `Tabs`, it's with `EnumDescription`. That's the template you're specialising, and it's obviously defined in namespace `A` or `A::Utilities` (your code doesn't show if that's a NS or a class), so it must be specialised accordingly.

Comment: It is unclear if one or both or neither of ::A::Utilities::EnumDescription and ::A::B::A::Utilities::EnumDescription exist from OP question.

Comment: @Angew - `Utilities` is a namespace. Do you mean the compiler looks for `A::B::A::Utilities::EnumDescription`?

Comment: Note the first :: are needed for stuff being fully qualified. You can have Utilities sub-namespace in every of namespaces of your project.

Comment: @Pietro The compiler may look for it, but if it doesn't find it, it will try `::A::Utilities` too. The whole problem with your code is that you cannot specialise `A::something` inside `A::B`.

Comment: Using `::A::Utilities` I get the error: C2888: symbol cannot be defined within namespace 'B'.

Comment: @Pietro My point was that you can specialize ::A::B::A::Utilities::EnumDescription::descMap like your example 2 did but not  ::A::Utilities::EnumDescription::descMap